# Python `breakpoint()` attributeError - 'StringStream' object has no attribute 'readline'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a complex environment where I want to stop execution of the child process at the start. In js you have `debugger;` while Python's alternative is `breakpoint()` or `pdb.set_trace()`.

I tried placing `breakpoint()` at the start of the child code and it resulted in the following error:

```
...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/cmd.py", line 126, in cmdloop
    line = input(self.prompt)
AttributeError: 'StringStream' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

which happens because (I believe) there is no stdin for it to connect to. How can I fix this? All I want is to **stop the execution at the beginning** and then attach with VSCode.

// edit
I tried running the child process with `-m pdb` flag and it does indeed stop the execution but after I attach to the process in VSCode I cannot resume it in any way. VSCode uses `pydevd` so I guess pdb is still waiting for the debugger to attach?

Comment: The error is likely caused by the child process reading its standard input from a pipe while pdp tries to use readlines features from a terminal. A possible workaround would be to replace the `breakpoint()` call with a `sleep(xxx)`. That would give you xxx seconds to identify the child process and attach a debugger to it. An alternative would be to save the current standard input and redirect it to the terminal if it makes sense, before calling `breakpoint()`. Only a comment because I do not know the capabilities of VSCode Python debugger.

Comment: Have you tried the following code for your original requirements?  
`import psutil
proc = psutil.Process(pid)
proc.suspend()`

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT proc.suspend() results in a crash :/